# How to test the frontend for different countries

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have different stores for different countries.

I have also changed the checkout information depending on the country.

I would like to test if my logic works properly for each of the websites.

Is there a way to check the frontend for a website of a specific country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to give you an answer with the minimum information that you have provided, so that says **multi stores** says **multi views** so different `code store` for each store. To display the current store with his code, you can use thie code below:

To get the store details:

`$store = Mage::app()->getStore();`

To get the store code:

`$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();`

Or you can direclty go to the store by the url like this:

`www.domaine.com/?___store=en`  en = english for exemple, the code that you set in store view